# Dictionary for TeXShop

Tags: texshop, spelling

Is there any way to get a spell checker or synonym dictionary like "Thesaurus" for TeXShop? I only know that there is such a built-in dictionary for TeXstudio, but I would like to stay with TeXShop.

**EDIT:** If I misspelling a word on purpose, the word will be underlined in red, but no suggestions will appear. It only shows me "no replacement found". Some misspelled words aren't even marked as misspelled... any way to fix this?

Comment: Most of us use Cocoa aspell https://people.ict.usc.edu/~leuski/cocoaspell/home.php

Comment: As Allan Munn said cocoAspell works through Apple’s Spell Checker and understands LaTeX commands. BUT it hasn’t been updated in a long time and folks have had a bit of a hard time installing on recent macOS versions. TeXShop has some preferences to help the regular Apple Spell Checker skip LaTeX command but it’s just barely helpful. Oh, if you didn’t already know TeXShop has access to Apple’s Spell Checker built in.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that too @HerbSchulz
I think I do not need a spell checker anymore, because my built-in lexicon already has a spell checker and thesaurus integrated. Thank you both for your help!